# React 16 doesn't work with enzyme

Tags: node.js, reactjs, enzyme

I use React and enzyme library for testing. 
I migrated to React 16 and trying to run my tests.

Here is my adapter file:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test NODE_PATH=src/ jest --verbose",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "precommit": "npm run lint -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "0.55.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "1.6.1",
    "react-google-maps": "8.3.0",
    "react-modal": "2.3.2",
    "react-paginate": "^5.0.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.12",
    "react-tabs": "2.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "2.1.6",
    "recompose": "0.25.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "7.0.3",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "husky": "0.14.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-cli": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-css-modules": "1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.6.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "transform": {
      ".*": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules"
    },
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/enzyme-setup-file.js",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run `npm test`, I got an error: `react-addons-test-utils is an implicit dependency in order to support react@0.13-14. Please add the appropriate version to your devDependencies. See https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#installation`.

I tried to set up another version of react-addons-test-utils, but it didn't help. The problem appears when I try to import:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using enzyme version `2.x`. To use React16, migrate to enzyme version `3.x`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I need to use another version of enzyme.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [enzyme docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/react-16.html) on how to use enzyme with react 16.